# C# Как реализовать вывод случайных изображений в picturebox из ResorceFiles?

Tags: c#, изображения, случайные-числа, ресурсы, picturebox

Как выводить одно изображение понятно. А вот как реализовать вывод случайного изображения в один и тот же picturebox из ресурсов при нажатии btn_Click?

Например вывод одного изображения:

```
'private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         picBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
         picBox.Image = ResourceFiles.MyImg;
       }
```

В интернете ответа на свой вопрос не нашел.
Пробовал делать рандом с применением imageList и label, работает, но он качество изображений бьет и размер макс 256х256 точек, т.е. не подходит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Через `ResourceManager` файла ресурсов можно получить все ресурсы определенного типа (взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826111/how-to-get-all-images-in-the-resources-as-list)):

```
  var images = ResourceFiles.ResourceManager
                           .GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true)
                           .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                           .Where(x => x.Value.GetType() == typeof(Bitmap))
                           .Select(x => new { Name = x.Key.ToString(), Image = x.Value })
                           .ToList();
```

Дальше берем случайное изображение:

```
    var rnd = new Random();
    var image = (Bitmap)images[(rnd.Next(images.Count))].Image);
```

Comment: Так просто оказывается, а я голову ломал перебирая варианты. Спасибо за помощь!